# How to expand macros with python and libclang

Tags: python, c, libclang

Say I have the following C code.

```c
#define A 0x1800
#define MACRO_FUNC(in) (A | (in))
#define B 6
#define MY_MACRO MACRO_FUNC(B)
```

How would I use `libclang` python bindings to expand `MY_MACRO` to `(0x1800 | (6))`  or preferably to `0x1806`

Comment: Preprocessing alone would only produce `(0x1800 | (6))`.  It requires expression evaluation to produce 0x1806.

Comment: yes using the gcc/clang preprocessor via --save-temps would work.  however I am trying to build a tool, and i need to expand macros.  I may resort to building my own expander.